# Simple NASM program doesn't work. Segfault

Tags: assembly, push, nasm, segmentation-fault

I'm new to assembly, so I do not quite understand why my program does not work. It crashes through SIGSEGV. Here code of my ***test.asm*** file:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    push word 0x4f4b
    mov al, 4
    mov bl, 1
    mov rcx, rsp
    mov dl, 2
    int 0x80      ; writes 'OK' message into STDOUT

    mov al, 1
    mov bl, 0
    int 0x80      ; exit with code 0
```

**Commands:**

```
$ nasm -f elf64 test.asm
$ ld -s -o test test.o
$ ./test
```

**OS:** Ubuntu 17.10 x64

Comment: Use a debugger.  The high bytes of `rax` will be all be `0xff` after the 32-bit system call returns `-EFAULT`, so `eax=0xFFFFFF01` / `int 0x80` returns `-ENOSYS` instead of exiting, and then you execute whatever bytes are next.

Comment: Oh, I prefer to use **syscall** to use all the features of the x64 processor. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @МихайлоПрощук If you are writing a 64 bit program, you need to use the `syscall` based system calls.